# Target iFrame Body Using jQuery (Same Domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I am trying to target the `body` of an iFrame with jQuery and it isn't working.

Here is the code:

***HTML***

```
<div class="editor">
  <iframe id="editorf">
    <body>
    </body>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {
   $('#editorf').contents().find('body').css( " background-color", "none" );
});
```

The iFrame is located on the same domain but it is one generate by my CMS so I do not have access to it directly. How do I target the body of the iFrame and apply the css `background-color:none;`?

Comment: Any errors in your console? It's possible that you may be trying to access the contents before they are loaded...

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte - No errors are generated.

Comment: Not sure if it will make the difference, but you could try removing that extra space within the background-color string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra space in your css property string.

```
" background-color", "none"
```

Should be

```
"background-color", "none"
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X8wDX/1/